# WooCommerce updated 'Add to cart' text, does not persist

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

If the product is already in cart, you can change the text on add to cart button via this code:

```
//Change on Single product page

     add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_cart_button_single_product', 9998 );
     
    function custom_add_cart_button_single_product( $label ) {
       if ( WC()->cart && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
          foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
             $product = $values['data'];
             if ( get_the_ID() == $product->get_id() ) {
                $label = 'Go To Cart';
                break;
             }
          }
       }
       return $label;
    }

//Change on Shop page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_cart_button_single_product', 9998 );
 
function custom_add_cart_button_single_product( $label ) {
   if ( WC()->cart && ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
      foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
         $product = $values['data'];
         if ( get_the_ID() == $product->get_id() ) {
            $label = 'Go To Cart';
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   return $label;
}
```

While this works perfectly when you tap add to cart button but if you go back to shop page or any page for that matter and try to return this product page again, it will still show the "Add To Cart", rather than your custom text. Is this expected from Wordpress?

Comment: To be clear, that filter is Woo’s, not WordPress. Have you also tried [`woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text`](https://woocommerce.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/)? You probably need both

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes, I have added both of them. One for single product page and one for Shop page. Updated the question code for same